# Set all new files and folders within a directory 777 permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have set up a client area on my website: http://samberson.co.uk/clients/

When a user uploads a file, it makes a folder, within the 'files-folder' directory.

I have set the 'files-folder' directory to have 777 permissions, however, when a new folder is made, it has 764 permissions, meaning that it messes up the PHP script (client area) and so then it doesn't display the image.

Is there a way that I can make all new files and folders within the 'files-folder' directory have 777 permissions automatically?

Comment: Use `chmod()` on uploaded files.

Comment: Taks a look at phps umask settings.

Comment: Are you using mkdir('path',0777)?

Comment: ***Do NOT set the execute bit on user-uploaded files unless you like getting exploited.*** 764 should be *just fine* unless you're trying to edit the [ie: watermarking] in which case you'd want 766 or 666.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod('/home/path/directory/', 0764)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer our from the developer of the client area. He said to put `umask(0);` in the `index.php` file within the parent directory, just underneath the `set_reporting` call. Thanks for all your help!